# It occurs ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table, in studying <<Database System Concepts>>6ed

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table classroom
    (building       varchar(15),
     room_number        varchar(7),
     capacity       numeric(4,0),
     primary key (building, room_number)
    );

create table department
    (dept_name      varchar(20), 
     building       varchar(15), 
     budget             numeric(12,2) check (budget > 0),
     primary key (dept_name)
    );
```

The first two create sentence is right. But in

```
create table course
    (course_id      varchar(8), 
     title          varchar(50), 
     dept_name      varchar(20),
     credits        numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0),
     primary key (course_id),
     foreign key (dept_name) references department
        on delete set null
    );
```

It occurs ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table ...
I don't know how to fix it.
Obviously, it's data type of foreign key is consistent.

Comment: use proper syntax: `... references department (dept_name)`. The field names may be the same, but MySQL isn't going to assume that those are the fields you want to link together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get details on the error run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and look for the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR`. It should be something like this:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2013-12-04 09:50:19 139428000 Error in foreign key constraint of table test/course:
foreign key (dept_name) references department
        on delete set null
    ):
Syntax error close to:

        on delete set null
    )
```

The solution is to specify the column name of the parent table, like this:

```
create table course
    (course_id      varchar(8), 
     title          varchar(50), 
     dept_name      varchar(20),
     credits        numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0),
     primary key (course_id),
     foreign key (dept_name) references department (dept_name) 
        on delete set null
    );
```

P.S. You should be aware that the `CHECK` constraints in your `CREATE TABLE` statements do not actually do anything. As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.